# Iterating over each element of an array, except the first one

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumeration, idioms

What is the idiomatic Ruby way to write this code?

Given an array, I would like to iterate through each element of that array, but skip the first one. I want to do this without allocating a new array.

Here are two ways I've come up with, but neither feels particularly elegant.

This works but seems way too verbose:

```
arr.each_with_index do |elem, i|
  next if i.zero? # skip the first
  ...
end
```

This works but allocates a new array:

```
arr[1..-1].each { ... }
```

*Edit/clarification: I'd like to avoid allocating a second array. Originally I said I wanted to avoid "copying" the array, which was confusing.*

Comment: Your second one does not make a copy of the array.

Comment: @sawa It doesn't copy the array, per se, but it will create a new array with all but the first element, per documentation on `Array#[]`; am I misunderstanding the requirement?

Comment: I agree with your assessment. Two other options are to just use indices: `(1...arr.size).each { |i| ....ref arr[i] ... }` or a flag: `first = true; arr.each { |e| if first; first = false; next; end; ... }`.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that I want to avoid allocating a new array. That's what I meant when I wrote "not make a copy".

Comment: 'Copying' is not confusing terminology.  In fact, it is a term of art.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the internal enumerator is certainly more intuitive, and you can do this fairly elegantly like so:

```
class Array
  def each_after(n)
    each_with_index do |elem, i|
      yield elem if i >= n
    end
  end
end
```

And now:

```
arr.each_after(1) do |elem|
  ...
end
```

Comment: by far the best solution

Comment: I agree. Alternatively, the `each_after` method could be defined on `Enumerable` instead of `Array` and have the same effect, right? Seems like it would be useful for non-Array enumerators as well.

Comment: Very nice! Futher to @MattBrictson's suggestion, consider returning an enumerator if no block is given, to permit chaining.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to do this without creating a copy of the array.

1)  Internal iterator:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
start_index = 1

(start_index...arr.size).each do |i|
  puts arr[i]
end

--output:--
2
3
```

2) External iterator:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
e = arr.each
e.next

loop do
  puts e.next
end

--output:--
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks! Conceptually this exactly what I had in mind. Namely: enumerate the array, discard the first element, then process the rest. But the code is fairly wordy. I guess that's unavoidable?

Comment: Regarding #2, it should be noted that, by eliminating the block, you have widened the scope of what formerly was in the OP's block.

Answer (score 1):

OK, maybe this is bad form to answer my own question. But I've been racking my brain on this and poring over the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html) docs, and I think I've found a good solution:

```
arr.lazy.drop(1).each { ... }
```

Here's proof that it works :-)

```
>> [1,2,3].lazy.drop(1).each { |e| puts e }
2
3
```

Concise: yes. Idiomatic Ruby… maybe? What do you think?

Comment: `drop` will still create a new array, `lazy` only delays this activity until `each`  is called. Nice try though.