# Iterate elements in array, except the first two, but also using "each_slice"

Tags: arrays, ruby

Well, I have an array like this:

```
array = ["month", "value", "january", "30%", "february", "40%"] # etc etc ...
```

I'm printing the values in pair, I mean:

```
array.each_slice(2) do |m, v|
    puts "#{m}, #{v}"
end

Outputs:
month, value
january, 30%
february, 40%
```

Good, but I don't want that outputs: `"month, value"` (the first two)

I have trying doing this: (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29426300))

```
class Array
  def each_after(n)
    each_with_index do |elem, i|
      yield elem if i >= n # Warning : it doesn't work without a block
    end
  end
end

array.each_slice(2).each_after(2) do |m, v|
    puts "#{m}, #{v}"
end
```

And outputs this error:

```
<main>: undefined method each_after for ...
```

I think that the problem is with the `"each_after"` method, that is made only to use it without the `"each_slice"`.

**My question:**:

How I can modify the `"each_after"` method to work with the `"each_slice"` method ?

Comment: Don't ask how to fix your solution, rather, ask how to solve your _actual problem_. Your real question is how to remove the first two elements of your array.

Comment: @leaf Interesting comment, but I just want to learn how to do it with my solution.

Comment: @robe007 That's not how StackOverflow is designed to work, so you're bound to get people pointing it out. [Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Your code

[`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) returns an `Enumerable`, but you define your method for `Array`. Just define it for `Enumerable` :

```
module Enumerable
  def each_after(n)
    each_with_index do |elem, i|
      yield elem if i >= n
    end
  end
end
```

You can then use

```
array.each_slice(2).each_after(1) do |m, v|
    puts "#{m}, #{v}"
end
```

Note that you need to drop 1 element (a 2-element Array).

Without changing your method, you could also use `to_a` before your Array method :

```
array.each_slice(2).to_a.each_after(1) do |m, v|
    puts "#{m}, #{v}"
end
```

## Alternative

Just use [`drop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-drop) before [`each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) :

```
["month", "value", "january", "30%", "february", "40%"].drop(2).each_slice(2).to_a
#=> [["january", "30%"], ["february", "40%"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works, but it is possible to do it fixing my solution?

Comment: Very nice explained answer. Danke schön !